# XSD Validation in azure

Tags: azure, xsd, schema

I have several services which I would like to deploy to azure. 
Each service has an xsd schema which is placed in the project where the service is.
In the validation module I try to load the schema this way:

```
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
Uri baseSchema = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
string mySchema = new Uri(baseSchema, "LogInService.xsd").ToString();
XmlSchema schemaLogIn = XmlSchema.Read(new XmlTextReader(mySchema), null);
schemaSet.Add(schemaLogIn);
```

... but apparently the path `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is incorrect, and when I try to deploy the service I get the following error:

```
Could not find file 'F:\sitesroot\0\LogInService.xsd'
```

(on dev this code is working perfectly)

My question is, where am I supposed to put the xsd files - or how can I change the code above so it will work on the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

I think your path is correct, what is probably happening is that your xsd is not being included in the package that is being uploaded. Check the properties of the file, in particular the build action property to make sure it will be copied.

Comment: what should i choose in the "build action" in order to include it in the package?

Comment: Change the build action to Content.